# Correlations between the selected column and the rest of the data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation

My data is about 270 columns with 160.000 **mainly non-numeric observations**.

I need to find patterns and dependencies between the columns. 
As example, I need a correlation of the column "Material" to other columns.

```
Material   |  Name    |  Country | Vehicle    
----------------------------------------------
Bricks     |  John    |  A       | Car
Bricks     |  John    |  A       | Car
Bricks     |  John    |  A       | Motorcycles
Bricks     |  John    |  B       | Motorcycles
Concrete   |  Bill    |  B       | Car
Concrete   |  Bill    |  B       | Car
Concrete   |  Bill    |  B       | Car
Concrete   |  Bill    |  A       | Car
```

My desirable result is:

```
Name    - 100% 
Country - 75%
Vehicle - 50%
```

I tried:

```
library("GoodmanKruskal")
Cor_matrix<- GKtauDataframe(df)
plot(Cor_matrix)
```

but got: *Error in table(x, y, useNA = includeNA) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements*

or:

```
library("corrr")
df %>% correlate() %>% focus(Material)
```

*Error in stats::cor(x = x, y = y, use = use, method = method) :  'x' must be numeric*

So I am searching for a package and a code example which can handle non-numerics. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain de logic behind your desirable output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If columns in your `df` are of `factor` type, then you need to transform to numeric first.

```
df[] <- Map(as.numeric,df)
```

otherwise

```
df[] <- Map(function(v) as.numeric(factor(v)),df)
```

2. Then, you can run the following code

```
df %>% correlate() %>% focus(Material)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  rowname Material
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Name      -1    
2 Country    0.5  
3 Vehicle   -0.577
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Material = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), .Label = c("Bricks", "Concrete"), class = "factor"), 
    Name = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bill", 
    "John"), class = "factor"), Country = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
    Vehicle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Car", 
    "Motorcycles"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses the function `GKtauDataframe`, which tries to calculate the metrics for all 270 x 270 combinations simultanuously. That is too much.

However, as you mentioned, you want rather to compare **one** column against **all others**. This should be feasible, and not need that much memory. The function `GKtau` does this between a pair of columns:

```
GKtau(df[, 1], df[, 2])
```

To get the values for the 1st column against all others, simply call:

```
lapply(df[, -1], GKtau, df[, 1])
```

Sure, you can refine your output using something like:

```
sapply(df[, -1], function(di) GKtau(df[, 1], di)$tauxy)
```

which makes the output way more compact.